# Exception in java "java.util.InputMismatchException"

Tags: java, inputmismatchexception

So, I am working on a code for class and can't figure what is wrong. The code compiles and when I enter the file I'm searching for, I get this message:

```
Enter the name of the file: FanData.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at FanDriver.fillArray(FanDriver.java:76)
    at FanDriver.main(FanDriver.java:35)
```

Press any key to continue . . .

I'm using TextPad as my compiler and the text file is in the project. The following is the code that I have written (ignore the methods being called in the quotes as they are something I need to do afterwards):

```
 import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FanDriver
{
    private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        // Constant for the amount of elements of the array
        final int MAXSIZE = 100;

        // Declaring variables
        int amountFans = 0;

        // Declaring and initializing our array of fans
        Fan[] fans = new Fan[MAXSIZE];

        // Calling all of our methods
        amountFans = fillArray(fans, MAXSIZE);
/**
        listFanData(fans, amountFans);
        bubbleSortByAge(fans, amountFans);
        listFanData(fans, amountFans);
        bubbleSortByFan(fans, amountFans);
        listFanData(fans, amountFans);
        searchByAge(fans, amountFans);
        searchByFan(fans, amountFans);
*/

    }

    public static int fillArray(Fan[] array, int MAXSIZE) throws IOException
    {
        // Declaring variables
        int counter = 0;
        int age;
        String name;

        // Getting the file name
        System.out.print("\nEnter the name of the file: ");
        String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();

        // Opening the file
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        // Making sure the file was successfully opened
        if (!file.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("\nERROR: FILE DOESN'T EXIST. CLOSING PROGRAM NOW.");

            // Exiting the program
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // Reading all of the amounts from the file
        while (inputFile.hasNext() && counter < MAXSIZE)
        {
            name = inputFile.nextLine();
            age = inputFile.nextInt();

            array[counter] = new Fan(name, age);

            // Adding to our counter
            counter = counter + 1;
        }

        //Closing file
        inputFile.close();

        return counter;
    }
}
```

I do not have the code for the Fan class, just the class itself.
The file we are retrieving is the file FanData.txt, which looks like this:

Chris P. Cream
5
Scott Free
9
Lou Tenant
3
Trish Fish
12
Ella Mentry
4
Holly Day
3
Robyn DeCradle
12
Annette Funicello
4
Elmo
7
Grover
3
Big Bird
9
Bert
7
Ernie
3
Grover
9

The text file is line-by-line. One line is a name and the next is a number. I don't know how to format it correctly on here.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your text file are organized line by line?? like Chris P. Cream 5 then next line Scott Free 9??

Comment: No, it is organized like "Chris P. Cream" next line "5" next line "Scott Free" next line "9"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the delimiter in your input file.

The way you had instantiated your "Scanner"(without specifying any explicit delimiter) shall use default delimiter i.e. a whitespace character.

It seems that the "nextLine()" method in your case is not returning a "line".

It is rather returning a number or string(may be, you need check your file for that) [which is not matching with the pattern followed by your Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html).

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of the type mismatch. After your first read scanner will be pointing to a non Integer value.

try to print your name before doing

age = inputFile.nextInt();

you will get to know the issue.

Above mentioned are means to understand the mistake.

Solution for your problem

Try :

age = Integer.parseInt(inputFile.nextLine()); // instead of age = inputFile.nextInt();

Comment: The desired output doesn't incorporate me printing a name before other things (not coded) are executed. I formatted the text file above wrong. It reads "   "Chris P. Cream" next line "5" next line "Scott Free" next line "9"...  ," so Line 1 = String Line 2 = Int Line 3 = String and so on. I must be oblivious because the way I have it structured seems like it should make sense.:

Comment: The problem is newline in second line is not handled. ie After first loop 'name = inputFile.nextLine();' will read the newLine alone and consecutive 'age = inputFile.nextInt();' will fail because it will try to read "Scott Free".

Comment: Printing name won't solve your your issue. But trying that could have revealed the issue to you. You can even try debugging if you have visual debugger available instead of printing the value of name.

Answer (score 0):

Exception is because of type mismatch as you are reading a text value from textfile and directly assigning to an int type.

Exception will be resolved if you parse the value as an integer as below

*Integer.valueOf(inputFile.nextLine())*;